# A-FRAME problem safari ios 13 with Motion & Orientation Access

Tags: aframe

how are you?
I wonder if anyone was able to solve, or had any solution with A-FRAME after the upgrade of IOS 13?
I work with Virtual Reality (VR) and use A-FRAME, but after this update the browser SAFARI no longer has the feature "motion & orientation access", compromising all my projects and my clients.

If anyone can help, thank you very much!

Comment: fyi there's an active PR to add permissions request to A-Frame for iOS 13 support: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4303

Answer (score 0):

A proposed solution on [A-Frame Github](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4277) to request access to the API based on the new `requestPermission`:

```
DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
.then(response => {
  if (response == 'granted') {
    window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (e) => {
      // do something with e
    })
  }
}).catch(console.error)
```

I don't have an iOS 13 device to test on. If you can verify (and maybe open a PR on A-Frame) it will be appreciated.